# css select dropdown bold on some <option>'s

Tags: css, forms, select

On a select dropdown, I need to make certain items 'strong/bold'.

How can I do this?

Example of what I ideally require:

```
<option value="#"><strong>Andorra</strong></option> 
<option value="#">--Grandvalira</option> 
<option value="#">--Vallnord</option> 
<option value="#"><strong>Austria</strong></option> 
<option value="#">--Amadé</option> 
<option value="#">--Bad Kleinkirchheim</option> 
<option value="#">--Mallnitz</option>
```

Comment: settle for optgoups or build a "fake" js/css based drop down - also, possible duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you could use `:nth-child(N)`

```
option:nth-child(1), option:nth-child(4) {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Sotiris/sqshN/

Find more info and browser support for this pseudo-class at http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild

Comment: thanks for this... its great, but doesn't work in Chrome (fine in Firefox)

Comment: @user991830 doesn't support bold for `option` elements, but the pseudo-class works. Check this example that change the color http://jsfiddle.net/sqshN/1/

Comment: [Windows] Chrome has never allowed drop down styling since it uses the OSes API. I recall a discrepancy like that when trying to achieve something similar.

Comment: There is a Chromium issue for this. I added a comment, maybe some more votes would get someone to make this work: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44917&q=select%20styling%20bold&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified#makechanges

Comment: Your answer should *at least* mention that this is not a cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 44):

You actually can't.

The **closest** thing (you can't choose a bold item)

```
 <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
```

Which gives you this: 
[image]

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_optgroup

You can also build one of your own but it won't be input an input tag (you should use inputs of your own).

Answer (score 5):

Using css in the  works as a quicker, easier alternative

```
<option value="value" style="font-weight: bold;">SELECT ME</option>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do it with jQuery.

```
  $('#Your select').append($("<option></option>").attr.css("font-weight" , "bold").html("Bold Text"));
```

You'd have to add some logic to determine which options to bold, obviously.

Answer (score -2):

This also works (Firefox 50 and Chrome 55). Items 3 and 5 are shown in bold

```
   <style>
    .bld {font-weight:bold;}
   </style>
   <select>
    <option value = "1">Kanakangi
    <option value = "2">Ratnangi
    <option class = "bld" value = "8">Hanumatthodi
    <option value = "9">Dhenuka
    <option class = "bld" value = "15">Mayamalavagowla
    <option value = "16">Chakravaaham
  </select>
```