# In Angular js , how to make selected options bold in multiple select

Tags: html, css, angularjs, select

In Angular , Multiple select drop down with option like Select fruits , Apple , Orange , banana like this , if i select banana and apple - how to make this options look bold and change background ?

Comment: If you provide some code, it will be easier to answer the question

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) look the example bellow:

```
<select ng-model="myModel">
    <option ng-class="{'bg-orange' : myModel == 1}" ng-value="1">Orange</option>
    <option ng-class="{'bg-blue' : myModel == 2}" ng-value="2">Blue</option>
    <option ng-class="{'bg-black' : myModel == 3}" ng-value="3">Black</option>
</select>
```

And to change the background options you can do a normal css:

```
.bg-orange{
    background-color: orange;
}
.bg-blue{
    background-color: blue;
}
.bg-black{
    background-color: black;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Take a look in this answer: [select-dropdown-bold-on-some-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078927/css-select-dropdown-bold-on-some-options)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you can encapsulate your word with the `<strong>` element in order to get the text bold. And you can add a css class on the elements in order to change the background. `.myClass{background:red}`